# Run/Debug Apache Fineract using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mifos, apache-fineract

Github guides suggest building the war and running in embedded tomcat through gradle wrapper....

This takes a lot of time to implement code changes.....I would like to run the project from Eclipse/IntelliJ and debug, hot code replacement, etc.
The wiki guides to do this are outdated, did not worked for me because there are problems in the build path, the main class cannot be found, etc.

https://github.com/MifosX-WITH-PENTAHO/incubator-fineract

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to do run/debug the project is running using embedded gradle task and attaching remote debugger to it:

http://osdir.com/apache-fineract-developers/msg02767.html